# Is ReactNative's `accessibilityLabel` and iOS Label retrieved using iOS Accessibility Inspector one & the same?

Tags: react-native, appium, react-native-ios, webdriver-io

Is ReactNative's `accessibilityLabel` and iOS Label retrieved using iOS Accessibility Inspector one & the same?

Same goes for Android Text retrieved using UIAutomatorViewer

[image]

[image]

[image]

We are planning to rely heavily on *accessibilityLabel* in ReactNative for Appium /webdriverIO driven automated tests. Will it be sustainable?

Or shall we use in combination traditional iOS predicate / iOS classchain / Android XPath etc locators?

Answer (score 1):

According to RN docs http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/accessibility,
you need to provide accessible={true} prop to the element that you want to use accssibilty, then you can add accessibilityLabel to that element. for Ex :-

```
<TouchableOpacity
  accessible={true}
  accessibilityLabel="Go back"
  accessibilityHint="Navigates to the previous screen"
  onPress={this._onPress}
  >
   <View style={styles.button}>
     <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Back</Text>
   </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

you can more details about this in RN docs http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/accessibility.

Comment: That's correct. But could you please confirm - whatever string that we supply in the accessibilityLabel gets translated into 'Label' field in iOS Accessibility inspector/corresponding field in the Android.?